# Blazor WASM to work with testing local Auth server

Tags: cors, blazor, blazor-webassembly, fusionauth

## Problem

I am currently trying to get Blazor WASM (Web Assembly) to work with a local Auth client ([Fusion Auth](https://fusionauth.io/)).

## Attempted solves

I tried to change the Cors policy on my Fusion Auth client. Additionally, I have tried to enable CORS on blazor WASM, but came to the conclusion that its not Blazor's job to care about CORS. It's a server thing. [image]

## Questions

I have two questions that I believe these are each related to CORS as well and probably only an issue because I am on localhost.

1. I am not getting a clean redirect to FusionAuth. Though, it does eventually redirect to the provider.
   [image]

> Refused to display 'http://localhost:9011/oauth2/authorize?client_id=ff87ab0d-0a7e-4bcc-af02-8fbf31a92b66&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=openid profile openid&state=30eaea5137a6491eb2447547c6948c7a&code_challenge=6KbxXv06jvGjTIG_KxvY2K6HRHy9v52z22usno4BnYk&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&response_mode=query' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

2. Once I login and get back from Fusion Auth, I get the following error:[image]

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9011/oauth2/token' from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> And
> POST http://localhost:9011/oauth2/token net::ERR_FAILED

## My Setup

My Program.cs file looks like the following:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("FusionAuth_test", options.ProviderOptions);

            options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
            options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback";
            options.ProviderOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:5001/";
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("openid");
        });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Where FusionAuth_Test config looks like the following:

```
{
  "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "33333333-3333-3333-33333333333333333"
  },
  "FusionAuth_test": {
    "Authority": "http://localhost:9011",
    "ClientId": "myIDhere"
  }
}
```

## To Replicate

1. Use the new .NET 5 sdk.
2. `dotnet new blazorwasm -au Individual -o BlazorAuthSample5` in the CLI/powershell
3. copy my Program.cs into yours. Only a few lines added/replaced.
4. change wwwroot/appsettings.json to include your fusionAuth clientId (or other local auth provider). Fusion auth can be set up via docker like so

```
curl -o docker-compose.yml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-containers/master/docker/fusionauth/docker-compose.yml
curl -o .env https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-containers/master/docker/fusionauth/.env
docker-compose up
```

5. `dotnet run` on folder and try to login

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: No. Basically this is a FusionAuth problem that doesn't play well with Blazor. I would recommend contacting them to get more info. This thread has a small bit more info. https://fusionauth.io/community/forum/topic/547/blazor-wasm-auth/7

It ended up being such an issue for us we had to switch to Auth0

Answer (score 0):

The error in your browser console is because FusionAuth is adding the HTTP response header of `X-Frame-Options: DENY`.

By default, this header will be added unless you register the origin with FusionAuth in your OAuth configuration.

In the UI, navigate to `Applications > Edit > OAuth` and find the `Authorized request origin URLs` configuration.

Try adding `http://localhost:5001` to the `Authorized request origin URLs` and then attempt to recreate. This should cause FusionAuth to exempt this origin and not add the `X-Frame-Options: DENY` HTTP header to the response.

From [FusionAuth Core Concepts : Application](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/core-concepts/applications/#oauth)

> **Authorized request origin URLs** *OPTIONAL*
>
> This optional configuration allows you to restrict the origin of an OAuth2 / OpenID Connect grant request. If no origins are registered for this application, all origins are allowed.
>
> By default FusionAuth will add the `X-Frame-Options: DENY` HTTP response header to the login pages to keep these pages from being rendered in an iframe. If the request comes from an authorized origin, FusionAuth will not add this header to the response. If you wish to load FusionAuth login pages in an iframe you will need to add the request origin to this configuration.

Comment: We gave that a whirl already. It did not work. The "X-Frame-Options" is still denying.

Comment: What have you configured in your Authorized origin URLs and what is the value of your `Host` HTTP header?

Comment: Application -> OAuth -> Authorized origin URLS:  `https://localhost:5001` and `https://localhost:5000`. Settings -> System -> CORS -> Allowed Origins: `https://localhost:5001` and `https://localhost:5000`. I don't know what you meant by "`Host` HTTP header".

Comment: FusionAuth will retrieve the `Origin` header from the request, and compare that against your configured authorized origins. If it doesn't match, we'll add the `X-Frame-Options` header. What is the value of your `Origin` header, it should be shown in the network requests of your browser tools.

Comment: Hi @robotdan, there is no `Origin` header (perhaps that is part of the problem?). The `Host` header is `localhost:9011` (fusion auth's default local port). Here is a link to the picture of our headers. https://imgur.com/a/VusFoeU

Comment: That could be the issue. As a test, try accessing `https://localhost:5001` as `https://testing:5001` by adding `127.0.0.1 testing` to your `/etc/hosts` table, and then add `https://testing:5001` to your Authorized origin configuration in the OAuth configuration.

Comment: We did that, adding `https://testing:5001` to our accepted origins for the Application and in CORS. It produced the same error ("'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.") and had a similar request params (except with "testing" in the place of "localhost").

Comment: If this is the same thread as https://fusionauth.io/community/forum/topic/547/blazor-wasm-auth/3 - let's move it to the forum. Duplicate threads are difficult to maintain.

Comment: hi, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about my attempt to debug this issue in FusionAuth's forums [here](https://fusionauth.io/community/forum/topic/547/blazor-wasm-auth?_=1696428496534). Two salient points:

First, depending on how you initialize your Blazor WASM project, you may end up with one of two dependencies for handling authentication (identified in your `<project>.csproj` file):

`Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal`

or

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication`.

You want the latter. The `Msal` package has the latter as a dependency, and as best as I can tell is specifically designed for working with Microsoft's identity platform. Whereas the `Authentication` package just manages auth flows - notably the PKCE flow, which is relevant here.

Second, the main thing that doesn't play nicely between Blazor WASM and FusionAuth is "silent authentication". This is the attempt to authenticate behind the scenes via iframe. If this fails, the package falls back to a traditional redirect. With FusionAuth it always fails, (1) because of the `X-Frame-Options: Deny` header ([this GitHub issue](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/2095) seems to indicate that problem was resolved, but I couldn't get it to work without manually adjusting the header with an nginx configuration), and (2) because the FusionAuth /oauth2/authorize page doesn't support this method anyways. The only way I found a decent resolution was to override the default `AuthenticationService.js` file that comes with the `Authentication` nuget package mentioned at the beginning of this post, and import my custom file via `<script>` in the `index.html` file instead of the one from the package. Microsoft docs actually offer some guidance on doing this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Anwyays, I just copied the minified version out of my browser, because the only change necessary is to set the silent authentication timeout to 0, so it redirects immediately. As of 7.0.11, this is line 12474:

```
// var e = t.silentRequestTimeout || 1e4;
var e = 0;
```

Fixing this, along with setting up the WASM project correctly, got things working pretty smoothly. The only config I have for auth in my `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("FusionAuth", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles";
    options.UserOptions.NameClaim = "given_name";
});
```

and my `appsettings.json`:

```
"FusionAuth": {
  "Authority": "https://auth-domain.com",
  "ClientId": "client000-id00-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "DefaultScopes": [
    "email",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "RedirectUri": "https://application.com/authentication/login-callback",
  "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://application.com",
  "ResponseType": "code"
}
```

I set the logout redirect to just go back to my application, which loops back to the login page. You could do other stuff. Anyways, this seems like kind of a niche issue, but hopefully this helps anyone else trying to set this up.